# Where are the videos from 3rd party apps saved

Tags: settings, 7.5, storage, cleaning, whatsapp

I have whatsapp installed on my lumia 710 running on 7.5 tango. Yesterday one of my friends send a Picture and video but I deleted the chat later.

Now, I can find the image in pictures album **Saved**, but couldn't locate the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a 3rd party app is saving a video, its stored internal to that app.  The app itself would have to have a way to share it, such as emailing or posting to a share somewhere.  When you deleted it you probably toasted the video too.